# Simplest modifiable Python class/object in standard library?

Tags: python

The simplest object to create in Python is

```
obj = object()
```

However we can't add more into it:

```
In [287]: obj = object()

In [288]: obj.param = 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-288-78f3fb98506b> in <module>
----> 1 obj.param = 1

AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'param'
```

On the other hand, if we create a simplest class and then create an instance of that class, it is modifiable:

```
In [289]: class SimplestClass: pass

In [290]: obj2 = SimplestClass()

In [291]: obj2.param = 1

In [292]: obj2.param
Out[292]: 1
```

The question is: is there in python standard library anything like this `SimplestClass`, which is like `object` but modifiable? (I'd like to use it in education course to introduce objects before classes)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want since you're looking to introduce classes, but Python's dictionaries satisfy this requirement. The only difference is that they use square bracket notation for items instead of dot notation.

Comment: I want to introduce dot notation before dicts, and explain later that dicts are just like dot notation, but allow other keys rather than just strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) to create a nameless class and immediately create an instance:

```
obj = type('', (), {})()
obj.a = 1
print(obj.a)
# 1
```

However, you can still use `object` if you are willing to use `setattr`:

```
obj = object()
setattr(obj, 'a', 1)
print(obj.a)
# 1
```